# Symbolic power of an ideal associated to non-singular algebraic set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, ideals

Let $Z\subset \mathbb P^n$ be a reduced non-singular algebraic set and $I$ denote the saturated homogeneous ideal of $Z$. I have seen the following result without proof:

For all $ n\geq 1$, $I^{(n)}=(I^n)^{sat}$ where $I^{(n)}$ is the n-th symbolic power of $I$, and $(I^n)^{sat}$ is the saturation of $I^n$.

Any idea about the proof will be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that $(I^n)^{sat}\subset I^{(n)}$, since $(I^n)^{sat}$ is the largest homogenous ideal defining the closed subscheme $Z$.

Now for $s\in (I^n)^{sat}$ to show $$s\in I^{(n)}=\cap_{P\in Min(R/I)} I^nR_P\cap R$$
where $R=k[x_0, x_1,\cdots, x_d]$ and $Min(R/I)$ is the set of minimal prime ideals containing $I$.

By definition of $s\in (I^n)^{sat}$, $x_i^ms\in I^n$ for all $i$ and some $m$.

Given any prime ideal $P\in  Min(R/I)$, there is i such that $x_i\notin P$, but $x_i^ms\in P$, hence $s\in I^nR_P\cap R$.

Comment: Is the result true without the non-singular condition on Z? (I have edited the question and put the non-singular condition)